# Custom field on user page

Tags: entities, hooks

I'm trying to add a new fields with hook_form_alter on **user_profile_form**. From the core module right now there are:

Password confirm

Pass and re-enter pass

E-mail

This is the part of my code:

```
/*
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */

 function mymodule_form_alter (&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

switch ($form_id) {
        case 'user_profile_form':




        $form['account']['telephone'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('New mobile'),
        );

        $form['account']['pass_title'] = array(
        '#type' => 'markup',
        '#markup' => '<div class="profile-pass-title">Password change</div>',
        '#weight' => -6,
        );


        //krumo($form); 
        break;  
        }
}
```

As you can see I've added the telephone field into the form, but when I add text into that text field it doesn't save. The url is **user/%/edit**. I'm missing something.

The core fields password and email are properly saving.

The next thing is to do is when I add a new field on **user_profile_form** to be displayed into user/%.

Previously I've mention **admin/config/people/accounts/fields**, when I add a field from there let's say "telephone" it's working great. On **user/%/edit** is appearing as a form field and on **user/%** the result is rendering well. But my idea is: when I've added this field I want to have a title over the "telephone" field result. The title will be "Changing telephone" and bellow will be displayed the "telephone" field result (the result is what the user filled in the textfield on **user/%/edit**).

@Alfred Armstrong post helped a lot.

With The **Field group** module this is possible to achieve. It's amazing that on user_profile_form I can use fieldset and wrap the field into, it displays into user/%/edit  and on display field that render the results on user/% I can use different fieldset and with little CSS I can do exactly what I want. Many thanks to Alfred Amstrong for showing me this module and thank you all who helped me to find an aswer for this task. I wish I could add +1 to you all :)

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't display on the user/%/edit, but only on user/%"? You need to add some hard-coded text? Or you want it to be editable on user's profile page directly? If so, where will it be displayed?

Comment: I mean if I add a field "Contact info" field in admin/config/people/accounts/fields the user will see that as a field text, but my idea is "Contact info" to be displayed only in user/%. If I use hook_form_alter and type-markup with text it will not be displayed in user/%

Comment: I still don't get you. Where should it be editable and where should it be rendered?

Comment: "Custom info" should not be editable and will be displayed only in user/%. The other fields like: name, mobile...should be editable.

Comment: If you only need to display a static text / HTML piece, you don't need fields at all, you only need to theme profile page.

Comment: Yes, I only need to add a static text like title only on user/%, but I don't know how. I'm not sure what hook should I use?

Comment: Please read about [user-profile.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user-profile.tpl.php/7).

Comment: I've edited my thread.

Comment: Any reason not to just use the standard Field API and add the fields to the user entity?

Comment: Yes, Field API is ok, but I don't know how to display a title over the text field. I've added more details in my thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Field Group module](http://drupal.org/project/fieldgroup). That will enable you to group fields under a heading as you require. You can add groups on the form or on the display independently.

After you enable the module the display editor at Administration -> Configuration -> People -> Account Settings -> Manage Display will show a new entry to "Add new group". Add a new group of type fieldset, give it a title as required and set it to be "open" (not collapsible). You can then drag and drop individual fields into the group.

By default the group will display in a box. If you don't want that, the CSS to override it is pretty simple, eg:

```
body.page-user fieldset {border: none;padding:0;margin:0}
```

Comment: Yes, this is working great. I'm gonna add more details on the main thread. Thanks very much.